# Windows 8: .phar files, how do you want to open

Tags: php, cmd, composer-php, wamp

I'm trying to run composer on windows with wamp. I installed composer using the cmd prompt, and now I'm trying to run "composer update" for an SDK. However, when I type in "composer.phar update," windows asks what app I want to use to run this program. I want the command prompt to deal with it! How do I just run it through cmd, without this "what app" window coming up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set php.exe as your default application for phar files.

Comment: Just right click the file > properties > change > choose php.exe .

Answer (score 6):

`.phar` stands for PHP Archive

Usually `.phar`s take some arguments, so they are intended to be run from command prompt. Linux/BSD/OS X shell or Windows command prompt.

Linux `.phar` use case scenarios assume `.phar`s are copied to some /bin and renamed to be without .phar extension, so you can use a php archive as if you would use any other linux command. So I recommend following way of doing the same thing with Windows:

1. Put all your `.phar` files to one directory like `C:\php\phars`
2. Add `C:\php\phars` to system environment variables (right-click my `Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables`)
3. Start the elevated command prompt (find command prompt in start menu then right-click and select `Run as Administrator`)
4. Type the following commands, replacing the path `C:\phpdev\php\php542\php.exe` with full path to your PHP executable:

```
ftype PHARFile=C:\phpdev\php\php542\php.exe "%1" %*
assoc .phar=PHARFile
set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PHAR
```

Next time your should be able just to run Windows console (keyboard <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd.exe`) and type any of your `.phar`'s like `apigen.phar` followed by any command and it will work

```
C:\Users\acosonic>apigen.phar help
Usage:
...

Arguments:
 command        The command to execute
 command_name   The command name (default: "help")

Options:
 --xml          To output help as XML
 --format       To output help in other formats (default: "txt")
 --raw          To output raw command help
 --help (-h)    Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)   Do not output any message.
 --version (-V) Display this application version.

Help:
 The help command displays help for a given command:

   php C:\phpdev\phars\apigen.phar help list

 You can also output the help in other formats by using the --format option:

   php C:\phpdev\phars\apigen.phar help --format=xml list

 To display the list of available commands, please use the list command.

C:\Users\acosonic>
```

So this way lets you run `.phar` archives in a directory where you need to work, for example generating documentation in `C:\myproject\controller` without specifying full path to `.phar` as if you would if it's run without adding it to Windows path.

To explain what commands in step 4 did:

1. Created mapping HKCR.phar → HKCR\PHARFile
2. Created HKCR\PHARFile\shell\open\command = 'php.exe "%1" %*' [REG_EXPAND_SZ]
3. Extended HKCU\Environment\PATHEXT = '%PATHEXT%;.PHAR' [REG_EXPAND_SZ]

`*.phar` gets treated like binary/script, and `*.phar` execution works as long as a `*.phar` file is located anywhere in `%PATH%`.

Comment: Johni's method seemed to work, I don't know if both were needed to access the help for the phar.

Answer (score 2):

One can wrap `php` `*.phar` with `*.bat`, then the filename will be the name of the CLI command:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "C:/Program Files/PHAR/phpDocumentor.phar" %*
```

One can also use such a wrap to pass along default arguments; eg. `wp.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "C:/Program Files/PHAR/wp-cli.phar" --path="D:/SDK/wordpress" %*
```

Where pattern `%*` will capture and forward CLI arguments, as it is supposed to.
Alike this one can run `phar` alike any other CLI command, in a terminal window.

Comment: Many wordpress wp-cli.phar examples online use the linux short form command line `wp <command>`. If you use @Martin Z's example of `wp.bat` you can effectively enable the short form on windows, to make it easier to follow linux based examples. Wherever you choose to place your phars, like c:/phar, it must be on the path as suggested by @Alexsandar's answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if one wraps it in a batch script or with the registry, both appears valid... but a script can be checked in (it does more than just run a single command). Else you'd need a `*.reg` Regedit config, which registers `*.phar` file-type accordingly. `C:/Program Files/PHAR` could indeed be on `PATH`, while `PATH` isn't too portable either.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Instead of changing .phar's default program, which is not always easy in Windows, try just typing "php" in front of your command.

```
php composer.phar update
```